# How do I find the directory with the longest path?

Tags: linux, filenames, directory-structure

How can I find the directory with the longest path (contains the largest number of subdirectories) , in the current directory , using `ls ~ -R` commmand

Comment: Is `ls -R` a strict requirement? [It probably should not be](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 4):

GNU `find` can output the depth of a found name using the `%d` formatting specifier to its `-printf` predicate:

```
find . -type d -printf '%d\t%p\n'
```

This would output the depth of the found directories in or below the current directory, together with the directory's pathname relative to the `.` search path. The depth and the pathname are separated by a single tab character.

Assuming that pathnames may possibly contain newlines, to correctly pass this information on to other tools for sorting etc. this would be more safely written with `\0` in place of `\n` at the end of the format string.  You may then sort the generated nul-terminated list with GNU `sort`, and pick out the pathname with the largest depth with GNU `tail` and GNU `cut`.  The GNU variant of these tools are all able to process nul-terminated records if you pass the non-standard `-z` option to them, whereas standard tools all work on lines of text.

```bash
find . -type d -printf '%d\t%p\0' | sort -z -n | tail -z -n 1 | cut -z -f 2-
```

The final `cut` removes the numerical depth from the start of the string.

This would give you a nul-terminated string on standard output with the longest (deepest) directory pathname under the current directory.  If there are several pathnames of the same depth, this will give you the one that sorts the last lexicographically.

Answer (score 2):

The following will assume that your directory names don't contain newlines. If that is the case, the following will work:

```sh
find . -type d | awk -F'/' 'NF>max{longest=$0;max=NF} END{if (max) print longest}'
```

This will use `find` to search all sub-directories of the current directory. It will feed the output to `awk`, with field separator set to `/`, to identify the input string with the largest number of fields (= path components). That input string, if any, is printed in the end.

Comment: `find . -type d -print0 | tr '\n\0' 'x\n' | awk …` with the caveat that newlines are transposed to `x` characters in the final print

Answer (score 0):

Of course, parsing the output of `ls` is generally and justly frowned upon, but if you really want to do it with `ls -R`, something like

```
ls -R ~ | grep '/' | while read var ; do
        res="${var//[^/]}"
        echo "${#res} $var"
done | sort -n | sed 's/^[^ ]* //' | tail -1
```

should work.

Note: it is far from foolproof. If you have complicated directory names (like  a new-line or a `/` in the name) this script will fail miserably.